# xml align problems want relative layout with four imageviews to be in middle on any screen

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem for example I do 
[image]

like this at nexus 6 and when I change on smaller screen happens like :
[image]

Where and what I am doing wrong ? I am completly new at this xml. Never need it before. 
My xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_00"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSomething"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/zero"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is this 4 ImageView's to be in the middle. They should stick together and same space between right and left. And to fit any screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in a `LinearLayout` instead set to horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/zero"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription=""
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mjafko i'd suggest that you make your naming conventions better also, imageview6 isn't very clear and can make developing harder, a better name that tells you what the imageview is for would be a better choice

Comment: No worry's I will. Just open project and trow elements into to copy code here. Now just need to figure it out how to resize to fit screen. Bacsicly want it to have same space around images on every screen

Answer (score 4):

Why RelativeLayout? A LinearLayout with gravity center would be good.
Especially if you want that the images have the same size, you could play with the weight properties of LinearLayout.

Comment: Thank you. How can I manage to resize images to scale with screen size ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 4 ImageViews inside `LinearLayout` with horizontal gravity inside `RelativeLayout`.
Try to use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Relative layout for four images, use linearLayout with weightSum property. Below is the sample:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/zero"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/activity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:contentDescription=""
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/nine"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSomething"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:text="@string/_00"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```